# What is registration in Java?

Tags: java, registration

What is registration in Java? How do one registers a class to a method or another class?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to register "a class to a method"

Answer (score 2):

Registering is **saving a object reference** of one class to another.

For example,

```
   JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
   ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
          System.out.println("YOU CLICKED ME");
      }
   }; 

   button.addActionListener(listener); // register me
```

In the above code, Anonymous subclass of `ActionListener` object is **registered** to `button` object of class `JButton`. The `button` instance, in turn, will notify the click event by calling `actionPerformed()` method of registered instance that it saved.

Comment: Hi, John Woderfully explained.

Comment: Why did you call -"Anonymous subclass of ActionListener object is registered to button object of class JButton". As listener is the refid of ActionListener class.

Comment: @susan: ActionListener is an interface. The reference of anonymous class that implements ActionListener is passed to addActionListener()

Comment: @susan: An anonymous class is a local class without a name. An anonymous class is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the new operator. While a local class definition is a statement in a block of Java code, an anonymous class definition is an expression, which means that it can be included as part of a larger expression, such as a method call. When a local class is used only once, consider using anonymous class syntax, which places the definition and use of the class in exactly the same place.

Comment: @susan: [what is anonymous class in java](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_anonymous_class_in_java)